# How do I connect a 1/2" PVC slip joint to a 3/8" compression fitting on a sink faucet?

Tags: plumbing, water, sink, kitchen-sink

I'm trying to get water to my sink in an unconventional setup. I have a water tank and a water pump so I don't need a shutoff valve under the sink. I have 1/2" female PVC stubbed up, and I have the two female 3/8" compression connectors hanging down from the faucet with a merge connector bringing them into one (I won't have hot water). I'm just wondering what's the cheapest and easiest way to connect these two? I can't seem to find any connectors that would work. It would be easy but I can't figure out how to connect to the compression threading with anything that can go into 1/2" female PVC slip joint. I would really appreciate some help.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Glue a 1/2" slip x FIP adapter into the PVC fitting (this requires a short piece of PVC pipe also).
2. Thread a 1/2" MIP x 3/8" comp. adapter into the FIP fitting (use teflon tape on the threads.

NOTE- pictures are for reference of fitting type and may not link to the size(s) you need.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Unless there is one where the PVC branches off, I would think a  1/4 turn valve would be a smart addition.